# Returning output from scriptblock from Get-Job?

Tags: asynchronous, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to test out asynchronous functionality in PowerShell 3.

So I figured I would query the uptimes of some servers remotely, and wrote the following script:

```
function getServerUptimes() {
    # Obtain credentials for logging into 
    # the remote machines...
    $cred = Get-Credential

    $compsHash = @{
       "server1.domain.com" = $null;
       "server2.domain.com" = $null;
    }

    # Define an async block to run...no blocking in this script...
    $cmd = {
        param($computer, $dasCred)

        Write-Host "which: $($computer)"
        $session = new-cimsession $computer -Credential $dasCred

        return (get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -CimSession $session | Select PScomputername, LastBootuptime);
    }

    ForEach($comp in $compsHash.Keys) {
        Write-Host "${comp}"

        # Kick off an async process to create a cimSession 
        # on each of these machines...
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $comp, $cred -Name "Get$($comp)"  
    }

    $results = Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

    # Retrieve the job, so we can look at the output
    ForEach($comp in $compHash.Keys) {
        $dasJob = Get-Job -Name "Get$($comp)"
        Write-Host $dasJob.output
    }

}
```

However, I don't really seem to get back any output in the resulting `$dasJob` object, I returned the value in my scriptblock, where is it going?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the output (not including `Write-Host` output, of course) in the variable `$results`. In PowerShell you retrieve job output via `Receive-Job`. The property `Output` seems to always be empty (not sure why).